# Where are the rest of the TMessage missing params?

Tags: winapi, message, vcl, c++builder-10.4-sydney

The VCL `TMessage` class provides the `Message`, `WParam` and `LParam` members, but a window message has more members:

```
typedef struct tagMSG {
  HWND   hwnd;
  UINT   message;
  WPARAM wParam;
  LPARAM lParam;
  DWORD  time;
  POINT  pt;
  DWORD  lPrivate;
} MSG, *PMSG, *NPMSG, *LPMSG;
```

Where are the `hwnd`, `time`, `pt` and `lPrivate` members? I'm in specially need of the `time` parameter.

Is there a way to access the original message that `TMessage` is constructed from (or any other means to get the `time` parameter)?

I'm handling my messages in `TComponent::WndProc(Winapi::Messages::TMessage &Message)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where are the `hwnd`, `time`, `pt` and `lPrivate` members?

There aren't any such members in `TMessage`.

[`MSG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg) is the structure that the Win32 API uses in a [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#message-loop) to retrieve messages from a [message queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages), via the [`GetMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) and [`PeekMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew) functions, prior to dispatching them to [window procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-procedures) via [`DispatchMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage).  The `time`, `pt`, and `lPrivate` values are not delivered to a window procedure, however a window procedure can retrieve the `time` and `pt` values via the [`GetMessageTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagetime) and [`GetMessagePos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagepos) functions, respectively (the `lPrivate` value is not accessible).

[`TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Winapi.Messages.TMessage) is the structure that the VCL uses in window procedures that are created by the RTL's [`MakeObjectInstance()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.MakeObjectInstance) function.  This function allows classes, like the VCL's `TWinControl` and `TTimer`, to use non-static virtual `WndProc()` methods as Win32 window procedures.

In a [standard Win32 window procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)), there are only 4 parameters available - `hWnd`, `uMsg`, `wParam` and `lParam`.  An RTL-based window procedure ignores the `hWnd` (as it already knows exactly which object method to call), copies the `uMsg`, `wParam` and `lParam` values into a `TMessage`, calls the target `WndProc()` method passing it the `TMessage`, and then returns the `TMessage::Result` value back to the OS.

> I'm in specially need of the `time` parameter. Is there a way to access the original message that TMessage is constructed from (or any other means to get the time parameter)?

If the message comes from the message queue of the thread that is calling your `WndProc()`, you can use the Win32 API [`GetMessageTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagetime) function.  Or, you can use the Win32 API [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) function to install a [`WH_GETMESSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)) hook into the thread's message queue.

If your component's `WndProc()` is called in the main UI thread specifically, you can alternatively use the VCL's [`TApplication::OnMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnMessage) or [`TApplicationEvents::OnMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnMessage) events, which receive a copy of the original `MSG` structure.  Your component can use a private [`TApplicationEvents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents) object to hook the `OnMessage` event.

However, a window procedure can receive both [queued messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages) and [non-queued messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#nonqueued-messages), so if the message does not come from the calling thread's message queue at all, then there is simply no `time` (or `pt`) value available to retrieve for it, as non-queued messages do not go through the `MSG` structure to begin with.

> I'm handling my messages in TComponent::WndProc(Winapi::Messages::TMessage &Message).

`TComponent` does not have a `WndProc()` method.  Perhaps you are thinking of [`TWinControl::WndProc()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc) instead?

Comment: It added it to `TComponent`. I defined `virtual void __fastcall WndProc(Winapi::Messages::TMessage &Message);` and then registered it with `AllocateHWnd(WndProc);` to get the window handle. It works as a charm. I'm posting messages from various threads, I just need the timestamp for those messages.

Comment: @MaxKielland as long as you are *posting* the messages via `PostMessage()` , and not *sending* the messages via `SendMessage()`, then `GetMessageTime()` will work.